# Al realizar una transacción de muchos registros, las demas transacciones se quedan en la cola

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

En el segundo EJB se hace le for y eso provoca que todas las demas consultas a las base de datos se detengan hasta que termine. Como puedo hacer estre proceso y varios más de manera concurrente.

```
@Stateless
public class EjbPasarNv {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "ERP3PRODUCCION")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    EntityManager em;

    @EJB CatestatusFacade st;
    @EJB CatdepartamentosFacade deptos;

    //PrimerTrackingBulk tracking;
    @EJB EjbPrimerTracking tracking;

    public void pasarNvProd(String fac) {
        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            Object ob="1";
            Catestatus estado=st.find(ob);
            Object ob2=10;
            Catdepartamentos depto=deptos.find(ob2);
            Query query=em.createQuery("Update Jobs u SET u.idestatus=:estado, u.ubicfis=:depto where u.idestatus.idestatus='0' and u.jobsPl.factura.factura=:fac and u.habilitado=true");
            query.setParameter("fac", fac);
            query.setParameter("estado", estado);
            query.setParameter("depto", depto);
            query.executeUpdate();
            Query q2=em.createQuery("Update FacturasImportacion u SET u.enproduccion=true where u.factura=:fac").setParameter("fac", fac);
            q2.executeUpdate();            
            tracking.primerMovTracking(fac, em);
            em.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EjbPasarNv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Ocurrio un error y no se completo la transacción");


        }finally{

        }

    }


}

@Stateless
//@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class EjbPrimerTracking {


    @Inject
    private LoginBean loginBean;
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(EjbPrimerTracking.class.getName());


    public void primerMovTracking(String fac, EntityManager em) throws Exception {
        try {


            Query q = em.createQuery("select u from Jobs u join fetch u.ubicfis where u.jobsPl.factura.factura=:fac").setParameter("fac", fac);
            List<Jobs> jobs = q.getResultList();
            Date fecha = new Date();

            for (Jobs j : jobs) {
                Tracking track;
                track = new Tracking(fecha, loginBean.getIdemp(), "AUTO", "AUTO");
                track.setComputadora(loginBean.getHost());
                track.setIp(loginBean.getIp());
                track.setUbicfis(j.getUbicfis());
                track.setJobs(j);
                track.setTerminado(Boolean.TRUE);
                //LOG.info("Antes de Guardar Tracking");
                em.persist(track);
                j.setUltimo(track);
                LOG.info("**************************************************************************");
                j.setFuturo(Boolean.TRUE);
                j.setCuadre(j.getUbicfis().getEntraCuadre());
                LOG.info("antes merge");
                em.merge(j);
            }





        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EjbPrimerTracking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            throw ex;
        } finally{
            //em.close();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: No sé qué implementación de JPA utilizas ni el tipo de isolación en la conexión a tu base de datos o qué mecanismos de sincronización usas para ejecutar estos métodos. En el caso de Hibernate, cada vez que encola más operaciones dentro de una transacción p.e. haciendo un ciclo `for` (como mencionas) se demora más el tiempo de la operación porque tiene que colocar más elementos en el primer nivel de caché, por lo que se recomienda realizar un pre commit cada cierto número de iteraciones. Te recomiendo utilizar `em.flush()` cada cierto número de iteraciones p.e. 10 o 20 y evalúa la velocidad.

Comment: Utilizo eclipselink, en cuanto al tipo de isolación no le pongo nada asi que el default. Pero ya estoy leyendo al respecto y creo que uso el nivel mas alto que es TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE. Como puedo ajustarlo en eclipselink. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias. En este caso ajuste el nivel de isolacion y con es quedo.

Comment: Por favor publica una respuesta explicando cómo lo lograste. Yo no trabajo con EclipseLink y el poco tiempo que me dediqué a investigar el cambio de nivel de isolación no me fue suficiente para proveer una respuesta sólida y concreta. Imagino que tú sí lo lograste, así que por favor comparte el conocimiento :)

Comment: En el servidor glassfish en el apartado de pool conexiones hay una parte de transacciones y allá seleccionas el nivel de isolacion. En mi caso uso READ_UNCOMMITTED